# Is there a way to use rust functions in html button?

Tags: rust

I am messing around with the code from chapter 20 in the rust book. Is it possible to connect a rust function to a html button?

sort of like this

`<button onclick="rust_function()">Press Me</button>`

Comment: In the browser? I don't think any browser these days support scripting in Rust, do they?

Comment: This question is _far_ too broad to be answerable. "Connect" could mean something as vague as "invoke a POST request that's handled by a server running Rust on the other side".

Comment: Yes, if you are using Rust for WebAssembly, but this question is much too broad and thus not valid for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, directly, you can't.
When a function is called from an HTML page, it's runned by the client's browser.

A modern browser can only run javascript and webassembly.

In case you don't know, webassembly is a low level, assembly like language that your browser can run.

Rust projects [can be compiled into webassembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Rust_to_wasm) and used from a webpage. It's not always easy to compile an existing project into webassembly, since some operations aren't permitted. You can learn more about it [here](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/).